Homotopy lifting property from lifting criterion
Let $p:E\to B$ a covering space. Homotopy lifting says a map $h:Y\times I\to B$ can be lifted by $p$ if its restriction on $Y\times 0$ can be lifted, and this lift depends only on its restriction on $Y\times 0$. Lifting criterion says if $Z$ is good(locally path connected and path connected), then for $f:Z\to B$ such that loops in $Z$ are mapped to loops that can be lifted to loops based at some point $\tilde x_0\in E$(In particular if $Z$ is simply connected), there is always a lift, and unique lifting property says this lift depends only on its restriction on a point.
I see that lifting criterion and unique lifting really implies a stronger homotopy lifting property for locally path connected and simply connected $Y$, in this case path components and components coincide and $Z=Y\times I$ is simply connected, so in fact a lift of $Y\times I\to B$ depends only on its restriction on set of points chosen from various components of $Y\times 0$. Is this observation correct? What if $Y$ is not simply connected, is there an example that $Y\times I\to B$ doesn’t satisfy the condition of lifting criterion?(But it seems that the proof of lifting criterion and uniqueness uses path lifting property, so homotopy lifing is not at all useless even in good $Y$ case.).

Are you assuming $Y$ to be simply connected or not? If not, $Y\times I$ is not simply connected and its path components also need not be.

Thanks,i added that

Note that $Y\to Y\times I, y\mapsto (y,t)$ is a homotopy equivalence for all $t\in I$. So the lifting criterion for $Y\times I$ is satisfied iff it is satisfied for the restriction to $Y\times{t}$ for any $t\in I$.

Thanks. So lifting criterion is not that “general” from this perspective:)
